# VSCode behind a corporate Firewall, extensions show up "Failed to install"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm behind a firewall and we already whitelisted the following links, which successfully list's the plugins with their descriptions.

```
*.gallerycdn.vsassets.io
*.visualstudio.com
```

However, when we hit `Install` we get a `Failed to install` message with the following message

```
Error: corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
Failed to install `eamodio.gitlens`
```

I would suspect that we are missing some more links to be whitelisted, but they usually show up in the developer tools as a 403 or a network issue. Thoughts?